# How do I port forward my Computer that uses Bridging?

Tags: windows-7, networking, port-forwarding

I need to portforward my computer using bridged connection type.

Previously my router dialed my connection and there was an Port forward page in the router and by adding rules there , it worked

Now I have switched to bridging mode and dial my connection from Windows 7.How do I port forward now ? uTorrent is able to port forward using uPnP .

I need to open up a port , how do I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your windows now dials, then maybe you're directly connected, without need to forwarding any port.

Can you see in windows setting what your IP is, and then check if this is the same IP from www.whatismyip.com ? If both matches, no need to forward any port.

You can still have some firewall issues then...

Comment: it is same ! so there is no need to portforward ? after allowing windows firewall ?

Comment: If IP matches, then you are directly connected to the wild Internet. No need to forward anything, everything directly reaches your computer (so will worms and other kind of attacks).

Comment: thanks :) Abt worms and other stuff ... I got an firewall and av no problem